# How to calculate mean and SD between $T_1$ and $T_2$ based on mean and SD from $T_0$ to $T_1$ and $T_0$ to $T_2$?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, standard-error, pooling

I am performing a meta-review about the transition of control in semi-automated cars, for which I am trying to retrieve specific means and standard deviations. I am not sure if I am using the right approach to do so.

For each driver, the transition of control can be divided into multiple stages, beginning at stage $S_0$, going through stages $S_1, S_2, ..., S_{n-1}$ and ending at stage $S_n$. I am reviewing literature in order to see how much time passes on average until each stage is reached.

The literature I found generally reports the mean and standard deviation for the time needed from $S_0$ to $S_x$ (so, from $S_0$ to $S_1$, from $S_0$ to $S_2$, ..., from $S_0$ to $S_n$). However, I would also like to get an estimate of the mean and standard deviation from stage to stage (e.g. from $S_1$ to $S_2$).

For the mean time from $S_1$ to $S_2$ I suppose that I can simply subtract the mean of $S_1$ from the mean of $S_2$. However, for the standard deviation I can't imagine that I can do the same.
I've stumbled across following formula to calculate the standard deviation for difference between means using the standard error:

$SD = \sqrt{(SE_1^2 + SE_2^2)}$

Which I found here: http://personal.psu.edu/drh20/100/fall2012/lectures/lectureNotes/lecture31Nov14.pdf

The standard error for each stage could then be calculated using the formula:

$SE = SD/\sqrt{N}$

However, I can't tell, if this applies to my problem, because it is applied to two independent samples in the source. Can I use this formula for my problem, or is there another way to do it?

Comment: well $(T_2 - T_0) - (T_1 - T_0) = T_2 - T_1$ so you could get the mean by linearity of expectation, but for the SD you'd need to know the covariances.

Comment: So I can not use the formula using the standard error stated in my question? I assume that I would need the whole dataset to calculate the covariances, which I do not have access to unfortunately...

Comment: If you have the SD of both $T_2 - T_0$ and $T_1 - T_0$, I suppose you could use that. If those two differences are positively correlated with one another, that would be an overestimate of the true SD, so your inference would be conservative.